# Best way to compare 2 dfs, get the name of different col & before + after vals?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, compare

What is the best way to compare 2 dataframes w/ the same column names, row by row, if a cell is different have the Before & After value and which cellis different in that dataframe.

I know this question has been asked a lot, but none of the applications fit my use case. Speed is important. There is a package called datacompy but it is not good if I have to compare 5000 dataframes in a loop (i'm only comparing 2 at a time, but around 10,000 total, and 5000 times).

I don't want to join the dataframes on a column. I want to compare them row by row. Row 1 with row 1. Etc. If a column in row 1 is different, I only need to know the column name, the before, and the after. Perhaps if it is numeric I could also add a column w/ the abs val. of the dif.

The problem is, there is sometimes an edge case where rows are out of order (only by 1 entry), and don’t want these to come up as false positives.

Example:

These dataframes would be created when I pass in race # (there are 5,000 race numbers)

**df1**

```
+-----+-------+--+------+--+----------+----------+-------------+--+
| Id  | Speed |  | Name |  | Distance |  |          Location   |  |
+-----+-------+--+------+--+----------+----------+-------------+--+
| 181 |  10.3 |  | Joe  |  |        2 |          | New York    |  |
| 192 |   9.1 |  | Rob  |  |        1 |          | Chicago     |  |
| 910 |   1.0 |  | Fred |  |        5 |          | Los Angeles |  |
|  97 |   1.8 |  | Bob  |  |        8 |          | New York    |  |
|  88 |   1.2 |  | Ken  |  |        7 |          | Miami       |  |
|  99 |   1.1 |  | Mark |  |        6 |          | Austin      |  |
+-----+-------+--+------+--+----------+----------+-------------+--+
```

df2:

```
+-----+-------+--+------+--+----------+----------+-------------+--+
| Id  | Speed |  | Name |  | Distance | |             |  Location |
+-----+-------+--+------+--+----------+----------+-------------+--+
| 181 |  10.3 |  | Joe  |  |        2 |          | New York    |  |
| 192 |   9.4 |  | Rob  |  |        1 |          | Chicago     |  |
| 910 |   1.0 |  | Fred |  |        5 |          | Los Angeles |  |
|  97 |   1.5 |  | Bob  |  |        8 |          | New York    |  |
|  99 |   1.1 |  | Mark |  |        6 |          | Austin      |  |
|  88 |   1.2 |  | Ken  |  |        7 |          | Miami       |  |
+-----+-------+--+------+--+----------+----------+-------------+--+
```

diff:

```
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
| Race# | Diff_col | Before | After |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
|   123 | Speed    |    9.1 |   9.4 |
|   123 | Speed    |    1.8 |   1.5 |
```

An example of a false positive is with the last 2 rows, Ken + Mark.
I could summarize the differences in one line per race, but if the dataframe  has 3000 records and there are 1,000 differences (unlikely, but possible) than I will have tons of columns. I figured this was was easier as I could export to excel and then sort by race #, see all the differences, or by diff_col, see which columns are different.

```
            def DiffCol2(df1, df2, race_num):
is_diff = False
diff_cols_list = []
row_coords, col_coords = np.where(df1 != df2)
diffDf = []
alldiffDf = []
for y in set(col_coords): 
    col_df1 = df1.iloc[:,y].name
    col_df2 = df2.iloc[:,y].name
    for index, row in df1.iterrows(): 
        if df1.loc[index, col_df1] != df2.loc[index, col_df2]:
            col_name = col_df1 
            if col_df1 != col_df2: col_name = (col_df1, col_df2)
            diffDf.append({‘Race #’: race_num,'Column Name': col_name, 'Before: df2.loc[index, col_df2], ‘After’: df1.loc[index, col_df1]})

            try: 
                check_edge_case = df1.loc[index, col_df1] == df2.loc[index+1, col_df1]
            except: 
                check_edge_case = False
            try: 
                check_edge_case_two = df1.loc[index, col_df1] == df2.loc[index-1, col_df1]
            except: 
                check_edge_case_two = False
            if not (check_edge_case or check_edge_case_two):
                col_name = col_df1
                if col_df1 != col_df2:
                    col_name = (col_df1, col_df2) #if for some reason column name isn’t the same, which should never happen but in case, I want to know both col names
                is_diff = True
                diffDf.append({‘Race #’: race_num,'Column Name': col_name, 'Before: df2.loc[index, col_df2], ‘After’: df1.loc[index, col_df1]})
return diffDf, alldiffDf, is_diff
```

[apologies in advance for weirdly formatted tables, i did my best given how annoying pasting tables into s/o is]

Comment: So it seems you don't actually want to compare row by row, and instead want to compare if rows with the same `Id` are the same within each `DataFrame`. Is `Id` a unique key in each `DataFrame`?

Comment: it's not clear how your output relates to your input, and you should [edit] your question to fix the formatting of your code

Comment: Also, will each `DataFrame` have the same number of rows, with the same `set` of `'ID'`s

Comment: id might not be unique. the same person could be listed a few times. Each dataframe does have the same # of rows

Comment: it's possible the ID's would be diff, than thats a difference i'd want to return

Comment: Well the logic is just too iffy for me. It's like a row-by-row comparison, except it's actually not. Sure, in your example where the rows are misplaced and exactly match it's obvious what should happen, but it becomes an absolute mess if rows are displaced by 1 AND also have differences. It becomes ambiguous as to what the right `before` and `after` comparison is when there are multiple differences + row displacement.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works if dataframes have the same number and names of columns and the same number of rows, so comparing only values in the tables
Not sure where you want to get Race# from

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = df1.copy(deep=True)
df2['B'][5] = 100 # Creating difference
df2['C'][6] = 100 # Creating difference
dif=[]
for col in df1.columns:
    for bef, aft in zip(df1[col], df2[col]):
        if bef!=aft:
            dif.append([col, bef, aft])
print(dif)
```

Results below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Alternative solution without loops

```
df = df1.melt()
df.columns=['Column', 'Before']
df.insert(2, 'After', df2.melt().value)
df[df.Before!=df.After]
```

[image]